# Extract generic parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a simple `IFactory<OUT>` interface and two derived classes.

```
export interface IFactory<OUT = any> {
    create(): OUT;
}

// number implementation
export class NumberFactory implements IFactory<number> { ... }

// string implementation
export class StringFactory implements IFactory<string> { ... }
```

and there is a `calculate()` method that builds an object by using the given model.

For the following model;

```
const model: Record<string, IFactory> = {
    num: new NumberFactory(),
    str: new StringFactory()
}
```

the `calculate()` method returns an object something like below;

```
const result = calculate(model);

/// result
/// {
///    num: 1,
///    str: "str"
/// }
```

The question is, how I can know the type of the result? I tried to built-in typescript utilities but I cannot achieve it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *annotate* `model` as `Record<string, IFactory>`, you've already lost.  That causes the compiler to forget about any specific key-value relationship in `model` and instead widens it all the way to a thing with any possible keys and whose properties are any possible `IFactory` type.  That would be great if you wanted to add/modify/remove properties from `model`.  Otherwise, you should probably let the compiler *infer* the type of `model` for you:

```
const model = {
   num: new NumberFactory(),
   str: new StringFactory()
}

/* const model: {
    num: NumberFactory;
    str: StringFactory;
} */
```

Now you have a fighting chance of having `calculate()` keep track of the input types so that the output is what you expect.  Here's one possible implementation:

```
function calculate<T extends object>(model: { [K in keyof T]: IFactory<T[K]> }) {
   return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(
         model as Record<string, IFactory>
      ).map(([k, v]) => [k, v.create()])
   ) as T;
}
```

Here I'm using [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to view the output of `calculate()` as some object type `T` and the input as a mapped version where each property `T[K]` is wrapped with `IFactory` to produce `IFactory<T[K]>`.

Inside the function body the compiler can't really follow or verify that the implementation does this properly, so I use a few [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell it not to worry.  This places the burden of type safety on me, so I have to be careful.

Let's test it out:

```
const result = calculate(model);
// const result: {
//    num: number;
//    str: string;
// }

console.log(result);
/// result
/// {
///    num: 1,
///    str: "str"
/// }
```

Looks good. `calculate()` accepts `model` and infers `T` to be `{num: number; str: string;}`, and the implementation works at runtime also.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#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-ulIYDtiCm9IQtCOrlB9MS63sNodZpsDlOO2K430tIl53V5spEPmH3Epdt5DoRMsmNN2IgA)